# How can I segregate properties of DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, properties, methods, hour

I would like to write: if the result of the difference of 2 DateTimes is longer than 3 hours then.... stuff in the if statement happens. But I only need properties in seconds or minutes, can I extract just that from the DateTime object?

```
  if(diffResult > DateTime.Hour(3))
   {
   }
```

I also want to know if its possible to divide DateTime by periods. Say I want to split my diffResult (which is the difference between 2 DateTimes) into 3 periods or perhaps for every 3 seconds my counter gets one added to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first part:
You can subtract two `DateTime`s to get a `TimeSpan` there you can get the total of various units - for example:

```
if ( (secondTime - firstTime).TotalMinutes > 180.0) ...
```

or you could use `TimeSpan` directly:

```
if (secondTime - firstTime > TimeSpan.FromHours(3)) ...
```

for the secondpart you have to do some calculation yourself:

```
var diff = secondTime - firstTime;
var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(diff.TotalSeconds / 3.0);
for (var time = firstTime; time < secondTime; time += period)
{ /* do your stuff */ }
```

Comment: for (var time = firstTime; time < secondTime; time += period)
{ /* do your stuff */ } ---------- will this count the amount of periods in the difference between firsttime and secondtime?

Answer (score 1):

U can compare using the follow code:

```
  DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                dt = DateTime.Now;
                dt.AddHours(3);
                int h = (int)DateTime.Now.Hour;
                if (dt.Hour == h )
                   //Do something
                else
                   //do otherthing
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods your asking about return integer results. What exactly is your question? `DateTime.Hour(3)` would not even compile.

I think you are looking for **DateTime.Now.AddHours(3.0)**

I should be clear, the only reason this answer is this sparse, is because of the invalid code in the author's question which.  Since I don't attempt to guess at what people actually want, its up to the author, to clarify what he wants exactly.

All he has to do is subtract two `DateTime` values and compare it to a `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0);`

`if (date1.Subtract(date2) > time)`

```
{
//YourCode
}
```

For the second, this article should be useful:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/TimespanMultiplication.aspx